# Creating 2 AWS instances with an additional private interface with specific private IPs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to create 2 simple EC2 instances, but each with an additional private interface (specifically 192.168.50.101 and 192.168.50.102) which can communicate with each other on that 192.168.50.0/24 network?
The primary interface IP addresses can be default/dhcp assignments (ie: 172.x.y.z).
But the 2nd interfaces on the instances must be exactly as described above.

Eventually I want to be able to have Kubernetes or some command line script to be able to create the above pair quickly.

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that you are wanting to launch the Amazon EC2 instances in a VPC that has a CIDR in the `172.x` range. Therefore, it does not make sense to assign a `192.168.x.x` IP address to those instances, since those IP addresses are not part of the same IP range. Can you tell us _why_ you want to assign these IP addresses? Why not simply use the IP addresses that the instances have _already_ been assigned? They can communicate with each other on those IP addresses just fine.

Comment: This is my development environment.  I have dual network cards on each server.  One interface is public (or in this case, dhcp 172.x.y.z) and the other interface is hard coded to 192.168.50.101.    On the other server, the second interface is hard coded to 192.168.50.102.   I'd like to be able to test without having to modify my address scheme too much.

Comment: While it is possible to add multiple CIDRs to an Amazon VPC, I attempted to create a VPC with a CIDR of  `172.160.0.0/16` and then add an additional CIDR of `192.168.0.0/16`. It fails, saying that the address is restricted and _"Use a CIDR from the same private address range as the current VPC CIDR, or use a publicly-routable CIDR"_. So, it seems like you can't add these two private IP address ranges. Please note that addresses `172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255` are _NOT_ public addresses.